# Docker preserve images policy

Tags: docker, shell-script, docker-registry, repository, images

Can I configure Docker in a such way that it will store only certain amount of tags for the given image e.g. `docker images`

```
REPOSITORY                     TAG                                      IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myapp   02e56bac4ee3f27a4d5670a6ac0d578e3dd5b2e5   af154c422af8        2 days ago          1.25GB
ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myapp   d43d33c8e15a5578cf9f6831f94a18f94e9b932f   e9958837c2c5        3 days ago          1.25GB
ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myapp   3a97c3ac36f6c241fb061199c5d3347b9bbff94a   3e80e7a25667        3 days ago          1.25GB
ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myapp   12f9a2890c67d42eb050e7d06dd593ec932b1ee7   8c07b05cd756        4 days ago          1.25GB
ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myapp   7b55fb6a75c73d16cbc731050d29323ae6b90632   426530a5cc66        4 days ago          1.22GB
ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myapp   c222e88d6b24984f338091cc5600aabb62e0ac72   e65e650d2dd1        2 weeks ago
```

and I want to store locally only N **most recent** images. Can I configure some kind of policy or is there any common script that runs rotation with cron or something like that? Other best practices/suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up using this simple shell script

```
docker images -q --filter "before=ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myapp:02e56bac4ee3f27a4d5670a6ac0d578e3dd5b2e5" | xargs docker rmi --force
```

First you [filter your images to list](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#filtering) only those created before the latest one (you either know your recent tag or just use `latest` one)

The you [just remove](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/) those images with `docker rmi` piping it to [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)

You can invoke this on each deploy or setup a cron to do that periodically.

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe that there is a way to set this as a global policy.  However, there is a simple command you can run that will "prune" or remove your unused images.

You will want to use `docker image prune --filter [options]` to achieve this.  Check out the official documentation for information on how to best filter.  As a best practice you should be tagging your images which will make managing of them easier using tools like this.